# Firebase Messaging plugin from Flutter (FCM) not triggering onMessage callback on iOS when app in background

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM is working ok for me on iOS, except when the app is in the background: onMessage callback is not triggered. I get the notifications and they are processed correctly, but I need to update my notifications variable in the app, so I need to store notifications even if the app is in the background.

Reading FCM package [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging), I figured that onMessage should be called even if the app is in the background, but this is not the case. Has anyone solved this issue? I'm using **firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3**. I've seen many posts here and on Github about this, but changing payload does not to it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround thanks to this [article](https://medium.com/@demmydwirhamadan/working-well-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-in-flutter-tested-on-android-4eb91f45d45).

1. Add flutter_local_notifications package found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/).
2. Add this code to your main.dart:

   ```
   import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
   var flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
   ```
3. Add this code to your main() function in main.dart:

   ```
   var initializationSettingsAndroid =
       new AndroidInitializationSettings('icon_notif');

       var initializationSettingsIOS =
       IOSInitializationSettings();

       var initializationSettings =
       InitializationSettings(
           android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
           iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

       flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
           .initialize(initializationSettings);
   ```

It should work.

UPDATE:
For this to work, your notification payload can't have a "notification" field. What I ended up doing to make it work is sending two notifications: one with "data", and the other with "notification", to cover all the cases.

Comment: can you share the payload you used ? `firebase_messaging` version 8+ has changed the way for the set of push notifications